# Solving an ATR based strategy coding Error

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to develop a strategy based on comparison between closing price difference between last two bars and Average True Range value of second last bar. My coding is as follows -

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="ATR Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

atr = ta.atr(14)
v = atr[1]
a = close - close[1]
b = close[1] - close
 
longCondition = (close > close[1])
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("LE", strategy.long, when = a > v)

shortCondition = (close < close[1])
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("SE", strategy.short, when = b > v)
```

But I am experiencing false entry points, mainly on 15 minute chart, particularly on short side. If there is a way to fix the issue, please let me know. Thanks for your time. Regards.

Comment: Saying you have an issue does not help us. Tell us what the issue is. Share a screenshot maybe and show us a false entry and why it is false.

Comment: Okay I will do so...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `if`/`when` statements and debug long/short condition by adding bgcolor:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="ATR Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

atr = ta.atr(14)
v = atr[1]
a = close - close[1]
b = close[1] - close
 
longCondition = (close > close[1]) and (a > v)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("LE", strategy.long)

shortCondition = (close < close[1]) and (b > v)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("SE", strategy.short)

bgcolor(longCondition ? color.new(color.green, 80) : shortCondition ? color.new(color.red, 80) : na)
```